# Как правильно поместить в проект 80 изображений?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

Предстоит сделать приложение - тест из ~80 вопросов. В каждом вопросе используется изображение. Если каждую из 80 картинок продублировать под разную плотность пикселей, получится 400 изображений, что сильно скажется на его весе. Как это сделать правильно, чтобы минимизировать затраты памяти на устройстве?  Таргет на андроид.

Comment: какая ОС то ...

Comment: Пишу с помощью libjdx на android и ios

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь libgdx уже ios не поддерживает